# C++ more efficient way to replace the nested loop?

Tags: c++, queue, deque

I have two large deques which store serials, and I want to collect them into a queue of pairs.

In the first loop, I filter out serials2 based on s1 in a filter_func, it returns a relatively small deque of serials, and I'd like to make them pairs like {s1, s2} and put them into a queue for the following process.

For example:

Let's say  `serials1 = {0.......5000}, serials2 = {0.......6000}`

When `s1 = 2` in the loop, `filtered_serials2 = {3, 5, 8, 10....}`
I need to collect the pairs like `{2, 3} {2, 5} {2, 8} {2, 10}...` in the queue.

Here is my code, is there any efficient way in C++ to do this?

```
 std::deque<int32_t> serials1 = ...
 std::deque<int32_t> serials2 = ...

 std::queue<std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>> pair_queue;
 for (auto const & s1 : serials1)
 {
    filtered_serials2 = filter_func(s1, serials2);

    for (auto const & s2: filtered_serials2 )
    {
        pair_queue.emplace(s1, s2);
    }
 }
```

Comment: How does `filter_func` use `serials2`? When you profile out what’s the bottleneck?

Comment: The bottleneck is filter_func, it use tree structure to search serials that meet the requirements.

Comment: what is `filter_func` actually supposed to do, though? For example, is it returning values in `serials2` not equal to `s1`? What? The fact that `filter_func` seems to return a copy of values means it's at least O(`serials2.size()`), right?

Comment: It does spatial search (like Rtree) in serials2 based on s1.

Comment: In that case you probably want to build up your spatial data structure once so you can query it in log time rather than having the build-up be at best linear in `serials2`. It sounds like this is O(`serials1.size() * serials2.size()`) but could be O(`serials1.size() * log(serials2.size())`). But also, the alloc(s) for each  `filter_func` return value are annoying.